# Clean composer output from non readable characters in Jenkins' console output page

Tags: jenkins, encoding, composer-php

I have a Jenkins job to tweak, but no administration right on Jenkins itself.

I'd like to clean *composer* output from non readable characters, e.g:
the command is `composer update --no-progress --ansi` which outputs 
 [image: Reading composer.json of]
in Jenkins'console.

I didn't exactly get the the reason why Jenkins cannot output some characters correctly.
As per https://medium.com/pacroy/how-to-fix-jenkins-console-log-encoding-issue-on-windows-a1f4b26e0db4, I perhaps could have tried to specify `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` for *java*, but as I said I don't have rights for Jenkins administration.

How could I get rid of these 'squares' characters ?

Answer (score 0):

By pasting output lines into Notepad++, i noticed that these characters were backspaces. Hereafter how I've managed to embellish the output for Jenkins console :

```
# run the command, redirect the output into composer.out file
bin/composer.sh update --no-progress --ansi >composer.out 2>&1

# getting rid of backspaces
composer_out=$(cat composer.out | tr -d '\b')
# adding line feeds instead of numerous spaces
composer_out=$(echo "$composer_out" | sed -r 's/\)\s*(\w+)/\)\n\1/g')

echo "$composer_out"
```